# Error when i click "Manage category"

Tags: category, magento-1.9.2.1, error-log

When i click on manage category i got page error "There has been an error processing your request"

```
a:5:{i:0;s:120:"Sorgente modello "Webinse_DailyDeals_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Days" non trovata per l\'attributo "deal_update_days"";i:1;s:4173:"#0 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Sorgente modell...')
#1 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(203): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(MagenThemes_MTTheme_Model_System_Layout_Layout))
#8 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(MagenThemes_MTTheme_Model_System_Layout_Layout))
#11 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(MagenThemes_MTTheme_Model_System_Layout_Layout))
#14 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/defacosm/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/defacosm/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:77:"/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/187a670a9d2ce9a0ca7c4491862c7a34/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I work with Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Comment: This is an error from a not correctly installed or uninstalled third party extension (Webinse_DailyDeals).

Comment: @fschmengler the estension was unistelled a long time ago, why this error now? maybe i unistalled the extensione not correctly? how i can check this? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the extension Webinse_DailyDeals created an attribute `deal_update_days`. When you remove an extension, any changes it made to the database are still there. Unfortunately this attribute depends on a class of the extension and now that the extension is uninstalled you get this error because the class cannot be found anymore.

You have to manually revert the changes. In your case, by running the following SQL query (**make a database backup first!**)

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code='deal_update_days';
```

The only way to find out about these things is to look at the setup scripts (in the `sql` directory of the module) or to wait for errors like this one.